# My applet does not work repaint method. here is my code

Tags: java

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class rectangle extends Applet
{
    void slp(int x)
    {
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(x);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {}
    }
    public void init()
    {}
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {

        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            rectangle rect=new rectangle();
            g.drawRect(20+i,40+i,40,50);
            slp(10);

            rect.repaint();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Where's the exact problem? What do you expect and what do you get instead?

Comment: You Might need to provide more details of the problem to get a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are blocking the AWT Event Dispatch Thread (EDT). Use `javax.swing.Timer` (note the Swing one) instead of the for loop.

(Also `@Override` is useful, and sticking to the normal Java coding conventions.)